# Using core plot with xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I am trying to use core plot with an ios app I am writing, but I am unable to build after following the instructions to set up the library for use. I am getting the following message.

```
'CorePlot0' does not contain a valid pid
```

Sorry the tutorial I used is here http://recycled-parts.blogspot.com/2011/07/setting-up-coreplot-in-xcode-4.html

Comment: Anyone that can answer this question is either a genious or has followed the same tutorial as you are. Some more detail pelease (don't be lazy).

Comment: Thanks for editing. There is no mention of the word 'CorePlot0' in that tutorial. Please post some code (Stackoverflow isn't a magical place)

Comment: I am not using any code, I have followed the instructions and tried to build after linking the library. Nothing else.

Comment: Note that the 0.4 release of Core Plot is significantly out of date.  The latest snapshot available as of right now is 0.9, but I'd highly recommend not using that and instead going for the latest version in the Mercurial repository. Also, as I commented on Joshua's answer, we do have detailed step-by-step instructions on the project's wiki, which we try to keep up to date: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications

Comment: MAybe this link will solve your problem. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909518/core-plot-1-0-with-iphone-5-and-xcode-4-2-coreplot0-does-not-contain-a-valid
It worked for me!

Comment: I found this link useful to solve this problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909518/core-plot-1-0-with-iphone-5-and-xcode-4-2-coreplot0-does-not-contain-a-valid

Answer (score 1):

This has been [asked (and answered) a number of times](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=stackoverflow%20core%20plot%20xcode%204&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) on this site alone. The most helpful suggestion on those (many) similar questions that reference the blog post you mentioned says you should read that post's comments since the post refers to older code.

If all else fails, create a new test project and try following the (comment-updated) instructions again. If it still doesn't work, update your question with **much more detail** regarding what you tried and where it went wrong. Include build logs, run logs, etc. - we're not mind readers.

Comment: In addition to this, please read the library setup and compilation instructions on the Core Plot wiki: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications We try to keep these up to date as the project and Xcode changes.