# core plot 1.0 with iPhone 5 and Xcode 4.2 - 'CorePlot0' does not contain a valid pid Error on compilation

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2, core-plot

I have followed installation steps from the [core plot in Application](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications) url.
As defined in subject, core plot version is 1.0 which was tried with iPhone 5.0 Simulator in Xcode 4.2.

what I did :

1) I've simply copy one of the CorePlot Example (i.e : CPTTestApp-iphone) from CorePlot_1.0/Source/Example Folder to my Xcode project workspace.

2) Drag&Drop framework folder from CorePlot_1.0/Source/ in my example app.

3) Changed Header Search Path and User Header Search Path with string

> "${PROJECT_DIR}/framework"/**

4) and follows other steps as from the [core plot in Application](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications) url
like set other linker flags, added core plot and core plot cocoaTouch in target Dependencies and Link Binary With Libraries section.

5) Compiler for C in "Build Option" is "default compiler (Apple LLVM compiler 3.0)",

"CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h" file is also imported without error.

But on compilation time, application crashed with error "'CorePlot0' does not contain a valid pid" which is from "checkformisalignedlayers.d" file.

**Note :** the same example is working perfectly when executed from CorePlot_1.0/Source/examples folder.

does any steps are missing or anything wrong with the installation steps ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.CorePlot installation is working perfectly now.

as per existing example.header path details is set with framework path.and I've added framework directory in application.

but instead of adding framework directory in application only need to add **CorePlotHeaders** directory.

hope, answer could help to others.

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the similar error but on adding only the CorePlotHeaders folder to my xcode project solved the problem. Earlier I had the entire framework which I had downloaded in the project and it gave me that error.
Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

'CorePlot0' does not contain a valid pid

Caused when we validated project and changed from GCC to LLVM

Removed checkformisalignedlayers.d reference from project.

Built ok. Not sure how it affects charts.